# How to redirect to a subdomain of same app with a parameter in my SPA

Tags: asp.net, azure, redirect, iis, subdomain

I would like to know how to configure my domain records and IIS settings to have 2 subdomains like app.mydomain.com and admin.mydomain.com to point to the same SPA asp.net app, but the admin.mydomain.com should pass a parameter to do show a different page.

mydomain is hosted in azure and using trafficmanager.net

I have:
app.mydomain.com --> trafficmanager.net --> mysite.cloudapp.net

I want to add:
admin.mydomain.com --> mysite.cloudapp.net?someParam=1

Ideas?
Thx a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameter is always the same, you can use the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) with a rule in the web.config file similar to:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="false" xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^(admin\.example\.com)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/?someParam=1" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Just add your admin CNAME like any other DNS and an endpoint in traffic manager.

Comment: Thx a lot. That pointed my in the right direction. I had to remove the xdt Transform (but added later for the transformations) and install some intellisense from [link](http://ruslany.net/2009/08/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-1-1/) and [link](http://pastebin.com/8GGGHTBL). Just for someone else, it is important to note the admin vs www in the subdomain because if you redirect to same subdomain you will get a nice loop :)